# Bales for Straw Bale garden has already decomposed

Tags: vegetables

Our strawbales in our garden have already decomposed and now the plants are struggling.  We've put potting soil around the plants to shore up and hopefully preserve our harvest.  So far we've lost just the beans, and were able to save the tomatoes, zucchini, watermelon, and cucumber plants.   This is the 3rd year we've used the straw bales to garden with, but I'm not sure what caused them to disintegrate so quickly this year.  I'm also not sure we'll try this method again next year.  Our property boarders a hay field which tends to invade our garden, hence the straw bales and lots of garden fabric.  I'm thinking about going to boxes, but the harvest from our garden the past two years has been amazing.  Does anyone have any suggestions to prevent this from occurring in the future? Or is it better to just go to boxes and fight the hay?

Comment: We had the same issue.   We also had a really wet summer, I think the excess moisture and heat cause the bales to decompose faster this year.  We've used this method of gardening for a few years with overall good results.  Having a traditional garden isn't possible for us since our garden borders a Hayfield too.  I'm thinking of building some garden boxes to hold the bales together longer.   I'm not sure that will work but it's worth a try.